# Limiting the number of rows in the combined query using UNION

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, db2, union

Using DB2 database:

```
select * 
 from (SELECT table1.field1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY table1.field1)  AS RID FROM table1
UNION
SELECT table2.field1 
FROM table2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY table2.field1) AS RID order by field1) as t where t.rid <= 20
```

Above query returns 40 records, need to fetch 20 records only. This query simply tries to fetch 20 records from each query which makes total of 40 records.There may be case when query 1 will return 0 records but query 2 can return 20 rows. Suggest if someone has faced similar issue and solution if any?

Comment: You mean something like `LIMIT 20` ?

Comment: Have you considered LIMIT or FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `FETCH FIRST` combined with nested CTEs. This will fetch up to twenty of each table, prioritizing the rows from table 1 for a total of twenty:

```
SELECT b FROM
(
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 1,table1.field1 FROM table1 ORDER BY 2 FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY) t1
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT 2,table2.field1 FROM table2 ORDER BY 2 FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY) t2
) tt(a,b)
ORDER BY 1,2
FETCH FIRST 20 ROWS ONLY
```

If your tables don't contain too many rows, you may simply eliminate the inner CTE + FETCH FIRST and let the outer SORT +  FETCH FIRST do all the work.